# Polymorphism/inheritance issue with virtual class member function

Tags: c++, class, function, inheritance, polymorphism

I might have the wrong idea on exactly what polymorphism versus inheritance is, but basically what I'm trying to do is have ***classB*** derive from ***classA***, and create a ***classB*** which overrides a pure virtual member function of ***classA***, like so:

**classA:**

```
  /////////////////
 // CodeBlock.h //
/////////////////

typedef enum {
    CCBT_UNDEFINED,
    CCBT_FUNCTION,
    //...
} CODE_BLOCK_TYPE;

class CCodeBlock {
public:
    CCodeBlock::CCodeBlock();
    CCodeBlock::CCodeBlock(CString& source, DWORD startPos);
    CCodeBlock::~CCodeBlock();
    virtual CODE_BLOCK_TYPE CCodeBlock::GetType() = 0

    CString m_code;
    DWORD m_startPos;
    DWORD m_length;
    int m_numLines;
}

  ///////////////////
 // CodeBlock.cpp //
///////////////////

//...
CCodeBlock::CCodeBlock(CString& source, DWORD startPos) : m_code(source), m_startPos(startPos) {
    m_length = m_code.GetLength();
}

CODE_BLOCK_TYPE CCodeBlock::GetType() {
    return CCBT_UNDEFINED;
}
```

**classB:**

```
  /////////////////////
 // FunctionBlock.h //
/////////////////////

#include "CodeBlock.h"

class CFunctionBlock : public CCodeBlock {
public:
    CFunctionBlock::CFunctionBlock();
    CFunctionBlock::CFunctionBlock(CString& source, DWORD startPos);
    CFunctionBlock::~CFunctionBlock();
    CODE_BLOCK_TYPE CFunctionBlock::GetType();
}

  ///////////////////////
 // FunctionBlock.cpp //
///////////////////////

//...
CFunctionBlock::CFunctionBlock(CString& source, DWORD startPos)
{
    m_code = source;
    m_startPos = startPos;
}

CFunctionBlock::~CFunctionBlock()
{
    CCodeBlock::~CCodeBlock();
}

CODE_BLOCK_TYPE CFunctionBlock::GetType()
{
    //////////////////////////////
    // >> NEVER GETS CALLED! << //
    //////////////////////////////
    return CCBT_FUNCTION;
}
```

**main:**

```
CCodeBlock *block = new CFunctionBlock(L"function hello(){ print('hello') }", iPos)
CODE_BLOCK_TYPE type = block->GetType(); // ALWAYS RETURNS CCBT_UNDEFINED!
```

As you can see, ***GetType()*** always returns *CCBT_UNDEFINED*. Keep in mind that CCodeBlock is meant to be a 'generic' version of CFunctionBlock (as well as a few other like-minded classes, some of which contain a CCodeBlock 'm_parent' member variable), and is supposed to inherit any CCodeBlock member variables & member functions, as well as override a specific list of functions contained in CCodeBlock.

How can this be achieved? Would I need to resort to using templates (if that's even possible)?

Comment: btw, you don't need `CCodeBlock::` when you declare member functions inside class `CCodeBlock`

Comment: Also, the types don't match.  `CCodeBlock CFunctionBlock::GetType()` vs `CODE_BLOCK_TYPE CCodeBlock::GetType()`.  Does this code even compile?

Comment: @billz that was a copy/paste typo, with an exception to CFunctionBlock::GetType() -- which seems to have been the issue all along. After removing 'CFunctionBlock::', block->GetType() now returns CCBT_FUNCTION. So thanks for that! If you post this as the answer, I will credit it for you.

Comment: @Matthew again, copy/paste typo. The original names were JJCodeBlock, JJFunction, and _JJ_BLOCK_TYPE, but I decided to edit these for the sake of simplicity. Made a few mistakes in doing so. I'll edit my post to correct this issue.

Comment: @RectangleEquals: The code is still ill-formed and has some other issues. For the next time remember that people can only help with your problem if the question is really represents your true code. That is, take extra care in copying the exact code that is causing the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bring comment as answer:

you don't need `CCodeBlock::` when you declare member functions inside class `CCodeBlock`

Comment: The actual issue was in CFunctionBlock, not CCodeBlock. But that's close enough. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

There are several things wrong with your code. Member declarations **should not** have the class name as qualification (i.e. `CCodeBlock::` should be removed from the declarations). Leaving it there makes the code ill formed.

Besides that, the destructor of a derived type **will** implicitly call the base class' destructor, and you should not do it. If you call it manually, the base subobject will be destroyed twice, probably causing undefined behavior (if the base destructor is not trivial).

Now the particular issue with your code in `main` was probably more like this:

```
CCodeBlock *block 
     = new CFunctionBlock(L"function hello(){ print('hello') }", iPos)
CODE_BLOCK_TYPE type = block->CCodeBlock::GetType();
//                            ^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

In C++, qualifying a function call disables dynamic dispatch. The expression `block->GetType()` will be dispatched to the final overrider of the dynamic type of the object that the `block` pointer points to. But if you add the qualification: `block->CCodeBlock::GetType()` you are asking the compiler to call the overrider at the `CCodeBlock` level.

Comment: That makes sense. I've removed all base destructor calls from my source, thanks! And as far as `block->CCodeBlock::GetType()` goes, the goal was to make `block->GetType()` call `block->CFunctionBlock::GetType()` instead, which I was able to do once I removed _'CFunctionBlock::'_ from `CODE_BLOCK_TYPE CFunctionBlock::GetType();` in _FunctionBlock.h_

Comment: @RectangleEquals: You understand what I said in the answer regarding `block->CCodeBlock::GetType()`, right? I am not sure if it is clear enough: if you qualify the function call with a class name, you disable dynamic dispatch and force the call to execute at that level.